# How to insert member list with menu driven prolog program?

Tags: list, prolog, member, membership

The Question is-

**Write a menu driven PROLOG program to implement various operations on List such as- membership**

My ans was -

```
main :-
    nl,
    writeln(">   Enter a selection followed by a period."), nl,
    writeln(">   1. Run a query"), nl,
    writeln(">   2. Exit"), nl, nl,
    read(Choice),
    run_opt(Choice),main.

run_opt(1) :-
    writeln(">   Enter list"), nl,
    read(L),
    member(X,[L]).


run_opt(2) :- writeln("Goodbye"), nl.

run_opt(_) :- writeln("Invalid option"), nl.

member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|TAIL]):-
  member(X,TAIL).
```

This above program has problem and i can't insert member with menu driven insertion, like  i do this below without menu driven directly--

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|TAIL]):-
member(X,TAIL).
```

and the above program correctly executes when i put--

```
member(X,[1,2,3]).
```

and it displays members as-

```
X = 1
X = 2
X = 3
```

So, i need to do that thing with menu driven but i cant pass the list member in prolog.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should the answer be if you input `[1, 2, 3]`? Should the program print `true`, or a single element of the list like `1`, or should it print each element on a separate line, or should it print all elements in a list, like `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: `member(X,[L])` should be `member(X,L)`

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie the ans should print all list members like i have shown above  but it shows invalid option and singleton variable error.

Comment: @Kintalken i also tried member(X,L) it shows singleton variable [X] error andinvalid option when i put list member values.